# Can we ask "Interested with something"?

Tags: grammar

Can one be "interested with" something?  As an example, I have a co-worker that asks:

> "Are you interested **with** this position?"

Comment: Can you give some more details?  What is the native language of the co-worker? Were they speaking carefully or casually? Why do you think there is a problem here?  What would you use instead? Have you done any research (like checking for example sentences in a dictionary)? Finally, this isn't really about the grammar, but about preposition use. When you [edit] to add the details, can you find a better tag?

Answer (score 0):

No, but one can be "[interested **in**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interested)" something. Any good dictionary will show you plenty of example sentences.